# How to access associated model through another model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

UPDATE (specific and more detailed previous version is below):

I'm developing a TV station web site. Here are requirements for my Program section:

1. Each `Program` has ONE `Category`.
2. Each `Program` has ONE `Subcategory`.
3. Each `Category` has MANY `Subcategories`
4. Each `Category` has MANY `Programs`.
5. Each `Subcategory` has ONE `Category`
6. Each `Subcategory` has MANY `Program`s.

I want to retrieve all these three models to be associated. For example, I should be able to retrieve below data from my views:

While:

```
p = Program.find(1)
p_cat = ProgramCategory.find(1)
p_subcat = ProgramSubcategory.find(1)
```

I should be able to retrieve and also EDIT these:

```
p.program_category
p.program_subcategory
```

or

```
program_category.programs
program_subcategory.programs
```

You can see what I tried below to achieve these requirements. You may recommend me a totally different way or fix my mistakes.

Thank you

============================================================

I have 3 models. They are supposed to be nested in eachother.

> ProgramCategory > ProgramSubcategory > Program

Here are my codes:

ProgramCategory model:

```
 has_many :programs
 has_many :program_subcategories
```

ProgramSubcategory model:

```
belongs_to :program_category
has_many :programs
```

Program Model:

```
belongs_to :program_category
belongs_to :program_subcategory
```

As I create a new Program, I can set its Category and everything is fine. I can access them from both sides. For example,

```
program.program_category
```

gives me what I expected. and also

```
program_category.programs
```

gives me what I want to have, too.

BUT, -*here comes the question*-

When I try to access `program.program_subcategory`, I receive just a nil.

Eventhough my Subcategory's Category is set and my Program's Category is set too, why I can't access `program.program_subcategory` directly?

When I type `program_category.program_subcategories`, I receive all Subcategories owned by that Category. But I CAN NOT get Subcategories from directly a `Program` object.

My scheme is below. Any help is appriciated.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120926181819) do

  create_table "program_categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "program_subcategories", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "program_category_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
  end

  add_index "program_subcategories", ["program_category_id"], :name => "index_program_subcategories_on_program_category_id"

  create_table "programs", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "program_category_id"
    t.integer  "program_subcategory_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             :null => false
  end

  add_index "programs", ["program_category_id", "program_subcategory_id"], :name => "my_join1", :unique => true

end
```

Comment: did you try program_subcategory.program to list all the programs under that subcategory?

Comment: I did try program_subcategory.programS. It gives nil, too. It might give me the program object if I set Subcategory to Program object manually; but I want it to be gathered from Category model. Because Category model knows that it has Subcategories.

Comment: Category knows which subcategories it has, but it does not know to which of these subcategories the program belongs. In your design `programs` have foreign keys for both category and subcategory, thus each program can belong to some category and to some subcategory independently. See my answer for the nesting design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design is strange a bit. If you need nesting like

```
ProgramCategory > ProgramSubcategory > Program
```

then you need

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program_subcategory
end

class ProgramSubcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program_category
  has_many :programs
end

class ProgramCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :programs, :through => :program_subcategories
 has_many :program_subcategories
end
```

This way when you create a program you can assign a subcategory to it. And this subcategory is already assigned to category, so you can access it via `program.program_subcategory.program_category`

And you do not need `program_category_id` foreign key in `programs` because program is not connected to category *directly*, but via subcategory.

---

**UPDATE**

> 1. Each Program has ONE Category.
> 2. Each Program has ONE Subcategory.
> 3. Each Category has MANY Subcategories
> 4. Each Category has MANY Programs.
> 5. Each Subcategory has ONE Category
> 6. Each Subcategory has MANY Programs.

Then I believe that my answer is still valid. You see, my structure is the same as your description except `Each Program has ONE Category` (because rails has no `belongs_to through`). you `has one` is actually `belongs_to` (because it can belong to only one).

But as soon as `Each Program has ONE Subcategory` and `Each Subcategory has ONE Category` program's subcategory's category will be the ONLY program's category. You can have `p.program_category` by defining a method on a Program class:

```
def program_category
  program_subcategory.program_category
end
```

---

Now for the part of

> I should be able to retrieve and also EDIT these:
>
> p.program_category

Imagine you have a Program in subcategory Comedy from category Movies.

You say you want to be able to EDIT programs category directly (if I understood correctly), like this:

```
p.program_category = ProgramCategory.find_by_name("Sports")
```

But what you expect to be program's subcategory then? As soon as Sports have many subcategories? Do you expect it to be blank?

So in this design the only way to change program's category is to change program's subcategory:

```
p.program_subcategory = ProgramSubcategory.find_by_name("Tennis")
```

And this will manke program's category == Sports, because Tennis belongs to Sports.

**Note:** If you really want sometimes to change program's category directly, leaving its subcategory blank it requires another design of course. I do not think it is very difficult but it requires more work with less help from Rails AR Associations magic.

Comment: I'm gonna try this out tomorrow at office and notify you about the result, thank you in advence!

Comment: How may 'belongs_to' have 'through' option? Naturally I have a `ArgumentError: Unknown key: through` error when I perform everything you said. Result: no way.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right, sorry about that. I edited the answer. You can remove an erroneous `belongs_to :through` association. But you still can access category of the program's subcategory via `program.program_subcategory.program_category`

Comment: Nope... It doesn't work. Now even `program.program_category` gives an error.

Comment: But that is what I am telling you. Look at the hierarchy on top of your question, you stated you want to achieve: `ProgramCategory > ProgramSubcategory > Program`. You see, program is not connected to category directly, but via subcategory.

Comment: I want both @khustochka :) Lemme update my question. Thanks for your help effort by the way. See my question again in a minute

Comment: OK, I see. Could you please tell, do you expect program's category to be always equal to program's subcategory's category?

Comment: Then it seems to me my design is still valid. See the longer explanation in the edited answer, because it is impossible to type this all into a comment :)

Comment: thank you very much for your trying, I must confess that your solution doesn't work for me. Besides it doesnt look valid. With model modifications you've sent, now I can't access `program.program_category`. All i get is `undefined method error`. :(

Comment: I made no model modifications in the updated answer (except mentioning `program_category` method which seems you have not added as soon you are getting `undefined method error`). But please understand that no one will fix your application, people can only try to explain how Rails associations work and how they can be applied to what you describe as your requirements. So if you do not understand or disagree with the *explanation* feel free to ask, but the code is just an illustration to the explanation (it may have typos, it may not match your class names, var names etc).

Comment: Well, you're completely right. I really appreciate your help. Thank you very very much. I think I'm now able to get this working. See you in another question :D