# 3 or more model association confusion at Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

It has been almost a week since I'm trying to find a solution to my confusion... Here it is:

I have a `Program` model.
I have a `ProgramCategory` model.
I have a `ProgramSubcategory` model.

Let's make it more clear:

```
ProgramCategory ======> Shows, Movies, 
ProgramSubcategory ===> Featured Shows, Action Movies
Program ==============> Lost, Dexter, Game of Thrones etc...
```

I want to able to associate each of these models with eachother. I've got what I want to do particularly with many-to-many association. I have a `categories_navigation` JOIN model/table and all of my other tables are connected to it. By this way, I can access all fields of all of these models.

BUT...

As you know, `has_many :through` style associations are always plural. There is nothing such as has_one :through or belongs_to through. BUT I want to play with SINGULAR objects, NOT arrays. A `Program` has ONLY ONE `Subcategory` and ONLY ONE `Category`. I'm just using a join table to only make connection between those 3. For example, at the moment I can access `program.program_categories[0].title` but I want to access it such like `program.program_category` for example.

How can I have 'has_many :through's abilities but has_one's singular usage convention all together? :|

P.S: My previous question was about this situation too, but I decided to start from scratch and learn about philosophy of associations. If you want so you may check my previous post here: [How to access associated model through another model in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608683/how-to-access-associated-model-through-another-model-in-rails/12609575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why a join table where you have a direct relationship? In the end, a program belongs to a subcategory, which in turn belongs to one category. So no join table needed.

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subcategory   # references the "subcategory_id" in the table
  # belongs_to :category, :through => :subcategory
  delegate :category, :to => :subcategory
end

class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :programs
  belongs_to :category    # references the "category_id" in the table
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subcategories
  has_many :programs, :through => :subcategories
end
```

Another point of view is to make categories a tree, so you don't need an additional model for "level-2" categories, you can add as many levels you want. If you use a tree implementation like "closure_tree" you can also get all subcategories (at any level), all supercategories, etc

In that case you skip the Subcategory model, as it is just a category with depth=2

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category   # references the "category_id" in the table

  scope :in_categories, lambda do |cats|
    where(:category_id => cats)  # accepts one or an array of either integers or Categories
  end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  has_many :programs
end
```

Just an example on how to use a tree to filter by category. Suppose you have a select box, and you select a category from it. You want to retrieve all the object which correspond to any subcategory thereof, not only the category.

```
class ProgramsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @programs = Program.scoped
    if params[:category].present?
      category = Category.find(params[:category])
      @programs = @programs.in_categories(category.descendant_ids + [category.id])
    end

  end

end
```

Tree-win!

Comment: Nope... When I try to access program.program_category i get this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method`...

By the way, your second recommendation makes sense. In fact I'm just looking for something that will give me the thing that I want. No matter what it is. Can you suggest any resources about that tree stuff?

Comment: it would be program.category, not program.program_category.... Sorry I gave the classes a differnt name than expected.

Comment: I recently recommend (and use) https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree which, even if it's not straightforward to set up, having to write a migration by hand, it gives a lot of functionality and speed.

Comment: Nope.. I had already adopted your associations to my situation. So in my case, that's program_category. Because: `delegate :program_category, :to => :program_subcategory`. Its really weird. This shouldnt be this much hard to get. All I want is using singular instead of plural -and so arrays.

Comment: I'm really scared of this category stuff. I think I will pass building a category system. I was expecting Rails and ActiveRecord to make it very very easy to do such like adding has_one and belongs_to lines... I guess I must work much harder to gain some abilities at Rails. Thanks for your help. Eventhough I'm not done yet, I will accept your answer. Information you've given would probably work for some people.

Comment: It's easier than you think, try it. Don't bother asking for more help if needed.